# what will be the time complexity of finding documents with array that contains a specific value in MongoDB?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, backend

let say my schema looks something like this

```
product = {
    title : String,
    categories : [String(Ref)],
}
```

I can query the products using the following

```
ProductModel.find({ categories: "Sports" });
```

let say I have 10000s of products and each product has around 10 categories.
what will be the time complexity to query the products like this?
is it a good approach?

Comment: Looks like a O(N * M) considering that you may add more categories. If you decide to keep it at 10 , it is more or less O(N).

Comment: I think in practice we seldom talk about time complexity on database technology. Instead, we usually talk about execution plan for query performance. From the database's performance's perspective, your question's answer depends on many factors like the indexing, sharding... of your database. To start with, I would suggest you use [explain()](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/explain-results/#executionstats) to check out yourself.

Comment: If you create and index on the categories field, the complexity would depend mostly on how many documents match, not how many are in the collection.

Comment: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-multikey/ I found this, I think it is going to be constant only without any configuration alose. can anyone please confirm this?